# Как обновить кеш Google Play Billing Library?

Tags: java, android

Дело в том , что я использую   Play Billing Library в своем проекте и там все храниться в кеше - гугл сервисов. 
Когда я возвращаю купленный товар он должен пропасть в программе.
И это происходит только тогда -когда  кеш я почистил вручную.
Через сколько он должен обновиться автоматически?

Программа готова не нужно предлагать переделать всю программу!

Кто чем поможет спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

У BillingProcessor попробуй вызвать `loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle()`

*Извиняюсь если не сработает, так как я использую anjlab в которой библиотека биллинга от гугла*